# Given 2 strings, a and b, return the number of the positions where they contain the same length 2 substring

Tags: java

So here is my code to the above question. I am curious to know why the code doesn't work in all scenarios such as:

```
System.out.println(stringMatch("aabbccdd", "abbbxxd")); // Should be 1, but was 3
System.out.println(stringMatch("aaxxaaxx", "iaxxai")); // Should be 3, but was 5
System.out.println(stringMatch("iaxxai", "aaxxaaxx")); // Should be 3, but was 5
```

```
public int stringMatch(String a, String b) {
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length() - 1; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < b.length() - 1; j++) {
            String aSub = a.substring(i, i + 2);
            String bSub = b.substring(j, j + 2);

            if (aSub.equals(bSub)) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: You expected output is not very clear.

Comment: Your program is actually calculating the number of substring which are same of length two.

stringMatch("aabbccdd", "abbbxxd") = ab,bb,bb ( count is 3)
stringMatch("aaxxaaxx", "iaxxai") = ax,xx,xa,ax,xx ( Count is 5)
stringMatch("iaxxai", "aaxxaaxx") = ax,ax,xx,xx,xa (Count is 5)

What is your requirement if this is not expected output ?

Comment: How can an `int` can hold `1  3   X ` ? This is unclear.

Comment: @WanderiKabithi - as commented above, please explain this further in order to get satisfactory answers. For example, 3 for the first one seems reasonable to me, the second `String` has `aa` and 2 different `bb`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question asks you to put two Strings next to each other and check on how many positions they have the same set of two characters (be careful that they can overlop). In other words:

```
aabbccdd        aaxxaaxx         iaxxai
abbbxxd         iaxxai           aaxxaaxx
--^^---- (1)    -^^^^---  (3)    -^^^^---  (3)
 (bb)            (ax, xx, xa)      (ax, xx, xa)
```

As you can hopefully see, you need only one loop to do this, since you're always comparing the same indices of String a and String b. But your code has 2 loops. What is does is check if any two characters of String a are anywhere in String b:

```
   for string "aabbccdd":
Iteration i1:  Iteration i2:  Iteration i3:  Iteration i4: etc...
abbbxxd        abbbxxd        abbbxxd        abbbxxd
aa (0)         ab (1)          bbb (2)       bc (0)
```

You need to get rid of the first loop and then fix your loop to run until the 2 before the end of the shortest String so you don't get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
public int stringMatch(String a, String b) {
    int counter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; ((i < a.length() - 2) && (i < b.length() -2)); i++){

        String aSub = a.substring(i, i + 2);
        String bSub = b.substring(i, i + 2);

        if(aSub.equals(bSub)){
        counter++;
        }
    }
return counter;
}
```

Thanks [Faaiz Haque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10036369/faaiz-haque) for spotting the error in my for statement! Both statements must be true for the loop to keep running, not either.

Answer (score 1):

As Ashu mentioned, your program is actually calculating the number of strings which are the same of length two.

Take the first example you mentioned..
aabbccdd, abbbxxd

So your for loops are structured in a way where the 'aa' substring is being compared with each two letter substring in the second string 'abbbxxd'

In the end you have ab matching with ab, bb matching with bb, bb with bb again, 
(since you have 3 b's in the second string) and therefore you get 3 as the output, when really it should be 1, since only one bb is matched to the same position (third and fourth letters)

Answer (score 0):

One error is `< ?.length() - 2` as the iteration is for `i+2 < length()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static int stringMatch(String a, String b) {
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length() - 1; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < b.length() - 1; j++) {
            String aSub = a.substring(i, i + 2);
            String bSub = b.substring(j, j + 2);

            if (aSub.equals(bSub)) {
                System.out.println(aSub);
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print(stringMatch("aabbccdd", "abbbxxd"));
    System.out.println("****");
    System.out.println(stringMatch("aaxxaaxx", "iaxxai"));
    System.out.println("****");
    System.out.println(stringMatch("iaxxai", "aaxxaaxx"));

}
```

Use the above code to generate the substring matches. The output generated is following:

```
ab
bb
bb
3
****
ax
xx
xa
ax
xx
5
****
ax
ax
xx
xx
xa
5
```

Which is, in turn, a correct output as per your code. If you want a unique count for the matched substrings, you can try to insert substrings in a set and return the size of the set as the output of your function.

Comment: Is this not the same as OPs code, which they claim is giving incorrect output?

Comment: The output is correct if the intent is to find matching substrings at any position.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should find greater string :

```
String tempA = "";
String tempB = "";
if (a.length() > b.length()){
    tempA = a;
    tempB = b;
}else{
    tempA = b;
    tempB = a;
}
```

Then you need control some special cases such as when i equals `aTemp.length()-1` or j equals `bTemp.length()-1`.In this cases  `aTemp.substring(i, i + 2);` and `bTemp.substring(j, j + 2);` statements occur errors.

i should iterate until aTemp.length()-2

j should iterate until bTemp.length()-2

You need to store finded position to avoid duplicate counting (I did is by using ArrayList)

For this example : stringMatch("iaxxai", "aaxxaaxx")
The answer must be 3 :

ax : i**ax**xai a**ax**xaaxx

xx : ia**xx**ai   aa**xx**aaxx

xa : iax**xa**i aax**xa**axx

```
public static int stringMatch(String a, String b) {
  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  int counter = 0;
  String tempA = "";
  String tempB = "";
  if (a.length() > b.length()){//to find the bigger string
      tempA = a;
      tempB = b;
  }else{
      tempA = b;
      tempB = a;
  } 
  for(int i = 0; i < tempA.length() - 2; i++){

    for(int j = 0; j < tempB.length() - 2; j++){
        String aSub;
        String bSub;
        if (i == tempA.length() - 2){//when i == tempA.length() - 2 you need to take the substring(i to end of the string) 
             aSub = tempA.substring(i);
        }else{
            aSub = tempA.substring(i, i + 2);
        }
        if (j == tempB.length() - 2){
             bSub = tempB.substring(j);
        }else{
            bSub = tempB.substring(j, j + 2);
        }
        if(aSub.equals(bSub) && list.indexOf(aSub) == -1 ){//list.indexOf(aSub) == -1 means there is no element in the list
            list.add(aSub);//or bSub
            counter++;
        }
    }
  }
  return counter;
```

}